# Visual Studio 2010 (C++) highly unstable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

We recently moved over to Visual Studio 2010 from 2005 and the environment have turned out to be highly unstable.

I experience 10-15 crashes per day at random locations ,  msenv.dll and vcpkg.dll to mention a few. It can be while selecting text or compiling, not found any pattern.

The plugin we got is VisualX Assist but I doubt that there is a problem with that.

Anyone here at Stackoverflow that experience this and/or know if there is any updates to apply to a default installed VS2010 ?

Comment: So you have a brand spanking new VS release, with a plugin that was just released and claims support, and you're somehow sure there's no problem with the interaction?  Why?  Have you actually tested a clean VS 2010 install without any 3rd party extensions installed?

Comment: @Nick, absolutely...  "The plugin we got is VisualX Assist but I doubt that there is a problem with that." <---  how can you be so sure?

Comment: I ruled it out since I have one machine without the plugin where VS 2010 crashes from time to time.

Comment: "time to time" is not 10-15 times a day...

Comment: Its a build machine, not used as much as the development machines.

Comment: Have you tried the VS 2010 SP1 beta?

Answer (score 2):

My Visual Studio 2010, without any plugins, was similarly unstable when I first installed it.  I got updates from Microsoft Update, and it rarely crashes now.  I never bothered figuring out exactly which update was key.  It might have been a driver update, or an OS update, or a .NET update.

I'm running VS2010 10.0.30319.1 on 64-bit Windows 7.  It's still slow, and it occasionally becomes unresponsive for a minute or two, but it doesn't crash very often now.

If you're up-to-date, and it still crashes, I'd be very suspicious of all plugins.